# ¿Cómo escribo un input desde consola en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soy principiante en Python y he querido hacer un programa muy sencillo. La idea era crear un archivo, al que le llame 'contra.py. Ahí se encuentra el siguiente código:

```
c = 111222333444

a = int(input("Contraseña: "))

if c == a:
    print('a')
else:
    print('b')
```

Cómo podéis ver, el archivo define una variable ('c') con un número, que es la contraseña. Luego nos pide que ingresemos la contraseña y comprueba si es válida o no.

Lo siguiente era crear un segundo archivo, al que le llame 'hack.py' (el archivo no tiene nada de hacker pero bueno). Con este código:

```
import os

os.system('python3 contra.py')
```

Eso simplemente ejecuta 'contra.py', pero lo que quiero conseguir es que aparte de ejecutarlo también introduzca la contraseña, ¿es eso posible?
Gracias.

---

Perdón, ya está solucionado lo anterior. Tenía que cambiar "python" por "python3". Error de principiante.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que buscas es que el script `hack.py` "inyecte" texto en la entrada estándar del otro (`contra.py`), eso no puedes hacerlo con `os.system()`, pero sí con `subprocess.Popen`.

Esto sería lo que debería contener `hack.py`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(['python', 'contra.py'], stdin=PIPE) as p:
    p.stdin.write(b"111222333444\n")
```

Como ves, a `Popen` se le pasa como primer parámetro una lista de cadenas, que son la lista de argumentos del comando a ejecutar (el primero de ellos sería el nombre del propio proceso a ser ejecutado, en este caso el intérprete python). Además de esa lista se le puede pasar el valor `PIPE` a los parámetros opcionales `stdin`, `stdout` o `stderr`, para tener acceso respectivamente a la entrada estándar, salida estándar y salida de error de ese subproceso que vas a lanzar.

El constructor de `Popen()` te devuelve un objeto, que en este caso recojo en la variable `p`, a través del cual puedes interactura con la entrada/salida del subproceso recién creado. En concreto `p.stdin.write()` te permite escribir en su entrada estándar (que es de donde el otro leerá cuando invoque `input()`).

A `write()` hay que pasarle una cadena de bytes, por eso la `b` delante de las comillas. Otra opción es pasarle una cadena, pero codificándola a utf8, por ejemplo: `"111222333444\n".encode("utf-8")`. También hay que poner un retorno de carro al final (el `"\n"`) pues `input()` no dará por completa la línea hasta que encuentre uno.

En este ejemplo no he redirigido la salida estándar del subproceso, por lo que se seguirá viendo por la consola lo que éste escriba  con `print()`.

Si quisieras recoger desde `hack.py` la salida impresa por `contra.py` (no se vería por pantalla), sería mejor usar `p.communicate()`. Así por ejemplo:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(['python', 'contra.py'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as p:
    result, errores = p.communicate(b"111222333444\n")

if result.decode("utf-8").endswith("a\n"):
    print("Parece que hemos acertado la contraseña!")
else:
    print("Mala suerte")
```

En este ejemplo, la variable `result` contendrá el texto (en forma de cadena de bytes) que el proceso haya emitido por su salida estándar, y `errores` el que haya emitido por la salida de error (en este caso no hay nada aquí).

Podemos por ejemplo comprobar que la última línea emitida termina en "a".